# How does LDAP filter query work specially in Java LDAP/springLDAP?

Tags: java, active-directory, jndi, windows-server-2012, spring-ldap

How does the LDAP query work in :-
(i). Windows powershell
(ii). Java JNDI
(iii). SpringLDAP

Does the LDAP filter query in each of the above 3 approaches search only the first 1000 random ActiveDirectory(AD) records to match our filter string and if it does not find matching AD entry in those 1000 records it returns recordset of size 0, neglecting the post first 1000 entries?

Answer (score 3):

No. What you're suggesting wouldn't begin to make sense. It forms the entire result set and then returns up to 1000 entries. Which client you're using has no effect.